# Simple small c++ IDE

Tags: c++, ide

I'm looking for a small and simple environment to run small C++ samples. I hate opening visual studio and creating a project just for a single source file with 50 lines of code. The only requirement is to have stl support( smth like this http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php on desktop would be great).

Thanks.

Comment: Try [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: codeblocks? http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: For 50 lines of code, why IDE at all?

Comment: I usually go with a recent version of the gcc compiler, a Makefile, and an editor, such as vim or emacs.

Comment: `Notepad` (plus heavy use of `std::cout` as an alternative to a debugger).

Comment: You don't have to create a new project each time. I have a "quick_test" project that I reuse each time I just want to test something.

Comment: NetBeans IDE is cleaner, simpler than VS, has some IDE extras. But might be too much.

Comment: Similar to Bo: I use a "small" (batch-)script which generates a quick test project and then use cmake|msbuild from the commandline.

Comment: Since you installed VS: use any editor you want and run cl.exe from the command line.

Comment: Try Zinjai, or Code blocks or Quincy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List of C++ IDEs.

- [Codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26)
- [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php)
- [Dev C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) ([Heavily out of date](http://clicktobegin.net/programming/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/))
  ([New actively updated version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/))

List of online C++ compilers.

- [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) (GCC 5.1.1)
- [Coliru Editor](http://stacked-crooked.com/) (GCC 5.3.0)
- [Compile Online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) (GCC 4.9.2)
- [CodePad](http://codepad.org/) (GCC 4.1.2)

---

I'm going to recommend eclipse cdt. Even though creating a project in eclipse cdt is not any faster than Visual Studio, you can always create a project that you can reuse every time for small snippets.

Comment: Desktop IDEs were in question

Comment: @DavidGoshadze I noticed, but listing a couple of online ones can't hurt anyone.

Comment: @Edward you can create a project and reuse it in Visual Studio all the same. And it's not blurgh Java.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Yes, but as of yet VS2012 doesn't [fully support C++11](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport).

Comment: Fair point. Though I'd argue enough of it is there..

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi user defined literals, constexpr, those two alone are a big part of c++11, and those aren't the only that are not supported yet.

Answer (score 3):

One of the oppurtunities you have is [Devcpp](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html)

You can also take a look at this [maintained version of Dev-c++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/)

Comment: Please consider pointing to the following version of Dev-C++, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.6.1 (x64) or 4.7.2, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at this (rather comprehensive) [overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B). [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org), [CodeLite](http://codelite.org), [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) and [QtCreator](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Developer-Tools/) (although, the latter is pretty heavy-weight again) are AFAIK the popular open-source choices.

Comment: Please consider pointing to the following version of Dev-C++, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.6.1 (x64) or 4.7.2, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Answer (score 1):

[SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) is an editor I used to use. If I remember correctly it has short-cuts for build and run.